# write selected attribute on dinamically written options

Tags: php

two `select` tags - `months` and `years`:

```
<select class='sx' id ='sxa'>
<?php
$months = array('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC');
for($x = 0; $x < count($months); $x++) {
    $i = sprintf('%02d', $x+1);
    echo "<option value=" . $i . ">" . $months[$x] . "</option>\n";
}
?>
</select>

<select class='sx' id ='sxb'>
<?php
$current = date('Y');
for ($x = 2016; $x <= $current; $x++) {echo "<option>$x</option>";}
?>
</select>
```

Is there a way to insert attribute `selected` on current month and year ?

In case of years this is always the last option, while in months it could be on any index.

Comment: You're going to need to utilize javascript to get something like this implemented.

Comment: @AdamA, far in the past I have solved this with php using some kind of flag, or something like that

Comment: I misunderstood the question, I apologize! You're right, and as @Chine Leung below has pointed out, this should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the current month is equal to the `loop index + 1`.

```
$currentMonth = date('n');
```

Then in your loop:

```
<?php for($x=0; $x<count($months); $x++): ?>
    <?php $i = sprintf('%02d', $x + 1); ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"<?php if($x + 1 == $currentMonth) echo ' selected'; ?>>
        <?php echo $months[$x]; ?>
    </option>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Or if you want to echo it your way:

```
<?php
    for($x=0; $x<count($months); $x++){
        $i = sprintf('%02d', $x + 1);
        echo '<option value="' . $i . '"' . ($x + 1 == $currentMonth ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $months[$x] . '</option>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? No javascript.

```
$months = array('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC');

$match = 'SEP';

$buffer = "<select name='fieldname'>";

foreach($months as $value){
  $buffer .= "<option value=\"$value\"";
  if($value == $match){ $buffer .= " selected"; }
  $buffer .= ">$value</option>";
}

$buffer .= "</select>";     
echo $buffer;
```

Comment: but `$match` is dinamically changed by the time.

Comment: so then simply use $match = date('n');

Comment: or rather date('M').